# numpy adaptive threshold formula

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to compute a threshold value based on a grayscale image (numpy 2D array with point values between 0 and 255).

The formula is the following :

[image: equation]
<sub>(source: [sciweavers.org](http://www.sciweavers.org/tex2img.php?eq=T%3D%202%2F%28w%2Ah%29%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bw-1%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7Bh-1%7D%20S%28i%2Cj%29&bc=White&fc=Black&im=jpg&fs=12&ff=arev&edit=0))</sub>

Where w,h are the width and height of my image S, and S(i,j) the value of the point.

My implementation is the following :

```
h,w = sMap.shape
adapTresh = np.sum(sMap)*2/(w*h)
```

But for some of my images this total comes back >255, so I believe there's a problem somewhere, am I using numpy wrong (again) ?

I'm not familiar with Python, I started 2 days ago, so please forgive me if it's a stupid question.

```
print w,h
>> 411,410
print 2/(w*h), np.sum(sMap), adapTresh
>> 0 22461727 266
```

Comment: You should propably check what does the `2/(w*h)` return, as always gotta be cautious around division.

Comment: actually, it prints 0, but the calculation is correct at the end, so I believe the error is in the sum?

Comment: Try using 2.0 instead of 2

Comment: using 2.0, I get `266.592214112`

Comment: Are you sure this is correct formula for threshold ? Consider a plain white image with all pixel values `255`, the, according to your formula the value gets much higher than 255 , for example if we consider 10x10 image with all pixel values 255 the this formula returns `510`

Comment: I took it from the paper : http://www.evernote.com/shard/s58/sh/3c3fba87-b9e1-489b-9f8a-0b0d5d197279/3bd65a80ae1f4512fb638f2d999e191d

Comment: @ZdaR has the right idea: verify your code. Simplify your problem (maybe a 2 x 2 image) and make sure the formula gives you the answer you expect. Don't blindly rely on formulas in papers.

Comment: The problem is that in most cases this formula gives me the results I would expect :)

Answer (score 1):

Well the average value for all the cells in your matrix is:

```
avg = np.sum(sMap) / (w * h)
```

And in the extreme case, all cells are equal to 255, such that

```
avg = 255
```

For example

```
In [8]: M = 255 * np.ones(4).reshape((2,2))

In [12]: M
Out[12]: 
array([[ 255.,  255.],
       [ 255.,  255.]])

In [9]: M.sum() * (2.0 / sum(M.shape))
Out[9]: 510.0
```

So I think you just have your adaptive threshold function wrong.  Did you maybe intend

```
In [11]: M.sum() / sum(M.shape)
Out[11]: 255.0
```

Comment: mmm, I need to think about that, the formula is correct though, and it would be logical that a blank image generates a full mask. I've used the following paper as a reference : http://www.jdl.ac.cn/doc/2011/201311114474757481_a%20simple%20and%20effective%20saliency%20detection%20approach.pdf

Comment: There's your problem!  In your linked paper, S is defined as S(i, j) = s'(i, j) × f(i, j).  It's not a simple sum, you need to implement s'(x), f(x) and S(x)

Comment: which has been done alread, the saliency map is fine, renders as it should, no problem on that side, it's just the thresholding I can't seem to figure out :)